# "The echo" module in reason only plays the feedback sound

Tags: reason

When I use the "the echo" plugin in Reason (using Reason 11) and turn up the delay time, I do not get a sound immediately when pressing a key but, but after that delay time. That means I only hear the echo, not the sound that is "echoed".

I expect to be able to hear both.

How is that done?

Comment: There has to be some sort of dry/wet knob.

Comment: From the pictures i found on the internet, the dry/wet knob is in the top right corner of the plugin. With this knob you can adjust the mix between the dry input signal and the processed output signal. If you point it in between, you will get a mix of both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top right corner of your plugin you will find a dry/wet knob. With this knob you can adjust the mix between the dry input signal and the processed output signal. If you point it in between, you will get a mix of both.